# How can I reorder the panel tabs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gui

I know I can rearrange the panel tabs by undocking a panel and on redocking it becomes the leftmost tab, but is there a more direct way to re-order the tabs?

QGIS 2.12 Lyon

Windows 7 64 bit